# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type for inner class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I try to add third-party bean to my application:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "mqSocket")
    public ZMQ.Socket startServer() {
        try (ZMQ.Context ctx = ZMQ.context(1);
             ZMQ.Socket publisher = ctx.socket(ZMQ.PUB)) {
            publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");
            return publisher;
        }
    }
}
```

and I try to autowire this like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {    

    @Autowired
    private ZMQ.Socket mqSocket;
```

but it prints following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mqSocket'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
...
```

Comment: It should not be an issue. Inner class is supported. Is your `startServer` method called?

Comment: Is your configuration loading? Try seeting up a dummy bean (Simple String) and see if that loads from the same configuration.

Comment: Your `ZMQ.Socket` is closed right before `startServer()` returns. Is that expected behavior for you?

Comment: @Nicolas, actually not

Comment: You may add an `@Import` annotation on you `Application` like class

Comment: @Nicolas thanks, it works. please addd answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the [`@Import` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-using-import) on your Application like class.

Eg.:

```
@Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

}
```

Note: cf. @M.Prokhorov comments, the `ZMQ.Socket` is closed by the try-with-resource statement

Answer (score 0):

You created a bean with name mqSocket so I guess you have to use the `@Qualifier` annotation; try to change your code in this way:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {    

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mqSocket")
    private ZMQ.Socket mqSocket;
```

I hope it's usefull

Angelo

Comment: doesn't help for me